# 'this' keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to implement following for the current .packages if I have multiple  having .packages class?

```
$('.packages').each(function(){
    var sizeOfLi = $(".packages:last > li").width();
});
```

Comment: FWIW, this (no pun) has more to do with jQuery than with `this` as a general concept in JavaScript.

Comment: The question has changed significantly since I answered it. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? Your edit basically makes no sense since it works as it is (i.e. does something useful, although maybe not what you want).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var sizeOfAllLi = $(".packages:last > li").map(function() {
  return $(this).width();
});
```

The `map` function iterates over the jQuery collection and calls the function provided in the argument, with `this` set to the current element. It will collect all the return values in <strike>an array</strike> a jQuery collection (see comments). If you want an array, add `.get()` to the end of the above.

Inside the function, need to re-wrap `this` as a jQuery element so we can use the jQuery's `.width()`, since `this` is a bare DOM element.

Comment: *"It will collect all the return values in an array."* Which is wrapped in a jQuery object. Use `.get()` to get the actual array. (One of the weird things about jQuery's `map`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: A jQuery collection duck-types to an array, so using it as if it was an array is fine, AFAIK. `[0]` works as well as `.get(0)`, and it also carries all the primitives defined in the `Array` prototype. Is it not so?

Comment: @Amadan: No, jQuery instances don't have all the `Array.prototype` stuff, not even close. They have a couple of them, but no where near the full set: http://jsbin.com/iyojaz And more importantly, a couple of the things they have with the same name behave differently (`map` for instance, and `length` which doesn't have the magic action on assignment), which is even worse than not having it. Assigning to new elements (`foo[23] = x;`) doesn't update `length`. So although `[]` works to retrieve elements, for basically any other purpose, no, jQuery instances do not duck type to arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Oh, you're right, I just checked. `sort` is there, `reverse` is not... it's a mess. I thought it's cleaner. :( Anyway, thanks - I knew about `jQuery.makeArray`, but not about the usage of `.get` with no params.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".packages:last > li").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).width())
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need dolar sign and parenthesis at this

Comment: @Malyo: You do if you want to use the jQuery `width` function. `this` within an `each` loop is a raw DOM element, not a jQuery instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` answers are fine, or you can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var liSizeArray = $(".packages:last > li").map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();
```

The return value will be an array of numbers, the widths of the respective `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

this always applies to the event handler in jQuery, which is your ,,main'' selector of function.

Answer (score 0):

depend on what you want to do

if you want to get the width of `li` when selected :

```
$(".packages:last > li").click(function(){
  sizeOfLi = $(this).width();
});
```

map all the li size do as Amadan said

```
var sizeOfAllLi = $(".packages:last > li").map(function() { return $(this).width(); })
```

The `this` keyword refer to the current li in this case